# Error when trying to delete a hidden sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

If you start with two sheets in a spreadsheet, one of them hidden, and then try to delete the hidden sheet leaving only the visible one, you can not delete the hidden sheet.

```
function test_delete_hidden_sheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create("delete_hidden_sheet");
  var numSheets = ss.getNumSheets(); // 1
  var newSheet = ss.insertSheet().hideSheet(); // Sheet2.hideSheet
  var nameActiveSheet = ss.getActiveSheet().getName(); // Sheet2
  // ActiveSheet = Sheet2 (hidden)
  ss.deleteActiveSheet(); // ERROR: You can't remove the last sheet in a document.
}
```

**Note:** This has been reported as [Issue 2846](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2846), visit and star it for updates.

Comment: The error message is misleading. You should open an issue in the Issue Tracker ( http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list ) Issue tracker for this.

Answer (score 0):

in the meantime as a workaround you could try like below:

```
function test_delete_hidden_sheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create("delete_hidden_sheet");
  var numSheets = ss.getNumSheets(); // 1
  var newSheet = ss.insertSheet(); // Sheet2.hideSheet
  newSheet.hideSheet();
  var nameActiveSheet = ss.getActiveSheet().getName(); // Sheet2
  // ActiveSheet = Sheet2 (hidden)
  if(!newSheet.isSheetHidden()){ss.deleteActiveSheet()}else{newSheet.showSheet();ss.deleteActiveSheet()}
}
```

or more simply since `showSheet` has no effect on non hidden sheet just systematically show the active sheet before deleting it :

```
ss.getActiveSheet().showSheet() ; ss.deleteActiveSheet()
```